# Show Dialog based on item that's in recycler view with the adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display a `dialog` when the user clicks a specific item in the `recycler view`. Now i don't know how to do this but I was looking into using an `interface` from my main activity. The `adapter` would pass the item(`TextView` text) into the interface, the main activity would then accept the parameter item and display a dialog based on it. But I don't know how to do exactly that. Or if there is any alternative way

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private List<String> mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final ViewBinderHelper binderHelper = new ViewBinderHelper();


public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    // uncomment if you want to open only one row at a time
    // binderHelper.setOpenOnlyOne(true);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) h;

    if (mDataSet != null && 0 <= position && position < mDataSet.size()) {
        final String data = mDataSet.get(position);

        // Use ViewBindHelper to restore and save the open/close state of the SwipeRevealView
        // put an unique string id as value, can be any string which uniquely define the data
        binderHelper.bind(holder.swipeLayout, data);

        // Bind your data here
        holder.bind(data);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mDataSet == null)
        return 0;
    return mDataSet.size();
}

/**
 * Only if you need to restore open/close state when the orientation is changed.
 * Call this method in {@link android.app.Activity#onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)}
 */
public void saveStates(Bundle outState) {
    binderHelper.saveStates(outState);
}

/**
 * Only if you need to restore open/close state when the orientation is changed.
 * Call this method in {@link android.app.Activity#onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)}
 */
public void restoreStates(Bundle inState) {
    binderHelper.restoreStates(inState);
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private SwipeRevealLayout swipeLayout;
    private View tickOffLayout;
    private View infoLayout;
    private View displayedText;
    private TextView textView;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRevealLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
        tickOffLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tickOff_layout);
        infoLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_layout);
        displayedText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.displayedItemOnRecyclerView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkItem);
    }

    public void bind(String data) {
/*            tickOffLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "IS CHECKED");
                    textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    tickOffLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#52abff"));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(!checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "IS UNCHECKED");
                    textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                    tickOffLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9d9d9"));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });*/

        infoLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "IS CHECKED");
                    textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    tickOffLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#52abff"));
                    displayedText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if(!checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Log.e("Checkbox", "IS UNCHECKED");
                    textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                    tickOffLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9d9d9"));
                    displayedText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.define_background);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        textView.setText(data);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set up ViewHolder and ViewAdapter the right way and also handle onClick with a DialogFragment show upon click:

```
private class SimpleTitleDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    /**
     * View's elements
     */
    private TextView mTitleTV;

    // Good object instance
    private String mTitle;

    // Constructor
    public SimpleTitleDataHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        /**
         * Set elements
         */
        mTitleTV = (TextView)
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do anything 
        // Show dialog
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dialogFragment.show(fm, "tag");
    }

    /**
     * Function to update view's elements
     * @param user Good data to be updated to
     */
    public void bindData(String title) {
        mData = title;
        mUserName.setText(title);
    }

}


private class ActiveAuctionsDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAuctionUserDataHolder> {

    // Data list
    private List<String> mDataList;

    /**
     * Constructor, which takes list of data and assigns it to local variable
     * @param dataList
     */
    public ActiveAuctionsDataAdapter(List<String> dataList) {
        mDataList = dataList;
    }

    /**
     * Define behaviour on creation
     * @param parent Parent viewgroup
     * @param viewType Type of view
     * @return holder
     */
    @Override
    public BaseAuctionUserDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                View itemView1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_title, parent, false);
                return new SimpleTitleDataHolder(itemView1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Event that happens on cell append
     * @param holder Holder to append to
     * @param position Position of the cell
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BaseAuctionUserDataHolder holder, int position) {
        User data = mDataList.get(position);
        holder.bindData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        /** 
        * Here you can dynamically determine what layout to inflate for each element of a RCV
        */
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get number of items in list
     * @return Number of items
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: So my question is, How do i get the recyclerview onclick to show separate dialog for items. Take this example: I have 3 items(these items are shown with an arraylist) in my recyclerview list, Now i want that when user clicks 1 | 2 | 3, it shows a dialog "Clicked item 1", "clicked 2", "clicked 3", respectively. But it can't be with get adapter position because the list can have the ability to change at anytime, so that's why i need to get the text, to do soemthing like (if text from recyclerview item == "first"){display this dialog}.... Does that make you understand my problem furthermore?